# Symfony 1.4 improve doctrine save() method

Tags: performance, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have 500 entries in my db. In my backend I have action. For example:

```
 public function executeMyAction(sfWebRequest $request) {

 // Get some data from table
 $templates = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SeoTemplates')->findOneByEntity('training');

//Get data from other table(500 items)
 $trainings = Doctrine::getTable('Training')->getTraining();

  // Make some operations with data
  foreach ($trainings as $training) {

       $training->setSomeValue1('some_data');
       $training->setSomeValue2('some_data');
       $training->setSomeValue2('some_data');

  }

// Problem part (try to save)
$trainings->save();
}
```

save() performed for a long time. How to solve this problem? Is it possible?

In my problem part I have all known error **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save each record instead of a collection

```
$templates = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SeoTemplates')->findOneByEntity('training');
$trainings = Doctrine::getTable('Training')->getTraining();
foreach ($trainings as $training) {
   $training->setSomeValue1('some_data');
   $training->setSomeValue2('some_data');
   $training->setSomeValue2('some_data');
   $training->save();
}
```

or use Doctrine to update the records using a query

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->update('TABLE')
   ->set($val1, '?', $val1)
   ->set($val2, '?', $val2)
   ->set($val3, '?', $val3)
   ->where('id = ?', $id)
   ->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you! Second way is fast:-)