# Symfony 1.4, Doctrine speedup

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Im using Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine. My problem is: only this database request:

```
UserTable::getInstance()->find (1)
```

takes up 1 second, which I found very slow. I thought persistent connection may help, but I didnt experience any change. Any idea?

Comment: They can be **a lot of different** resources that can slow down your query. We do not have enough information in this case. There is no simple way to optimize MySQL that match every case...

Comment: what else can I post to inform you? I dont think that simple query can be made more simpler

Comment: If you're worried about speed why are you using an old symfony and an old doctrine? And why are you even using doctrine? It's kinda known for being slow.

Comment: @Steven there is nothing wrong with Doctrine whatsoever - I've used version 1 on hundreds of applications without any issues

Comment: @user1929946 there is more info required to assist here ... can you show your schema.yml for the table in question, can you tell us what environment you using ? dev / test / prod ? what db server are you using ? how quick is it if you run the query directly in the DB (ie via client tools) - `select * from table where id = ?`

Comment: @ManseUK Who said there was something wrong with it? I was just saying that it's slow. You can't deny that it's not slow lol. It's also old PHP 5.4/PHP5.3 and newest version bring a TON of performance improvements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961743/symfony-1-4-improve-doctrine-save-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, 1 second for a simple select seems quite long ... 
Some questions to check the origin of trouble:

- have you an index on your id column of your table ?
- how many rows in your table ?
  To be more quick, how many time to make the same request directly on your database (try your select * from xxx where id = 1 into phpmyadmin or other db manager).

If the request is quick in this case, you have to look to the following elements:

- is your database distant and what about your network speed ?
- what is the size of returned datas (UserTable fields) ?